# How to say that someone 'established' a job in company

Tags: sentence-construction

I would like to say that someone's achievement is that he was **the first person who was hired as a [role]** - for example: Marketing Specialist - the first Marketing Specialist in the company ever.

It should mean that he had to establish the responsibilities for the role, set up new processes throughout the company and convince his colleagues that the role has a value for the company.

I would like to say it more simply than I described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a verb or a noun, then the word **pioneer** might be what you are looking for. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pioneer), it means **a person who is one of the first people to do something**. It also carries overtones of setting up infrastructure in a new place.

In this situation, it would be best to use it as a verb:

> He pioneered the role of Marketing Specialist within the company.

Comment: Thanks! The word is great. If I would like to say it in a sentence that would say more than just the word - for people who don't understand the meaning of this word - how would you say it?

It should implicate the achievement of establishing the responsibilities of the role and changing the processes in the company.

Comment: @JoudicekJouda - Then just add that: He pioneered the role of Marketing Specialist within the company, establishing the responsibilities or the role and changing the processes in the company.

Comment: *of the role, sorry.